# Как в worpdress узнать из самого shortcod-а сколько shortcod-ов на странице?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Мне нужно вкладывать данные в объект Window. Если выполнять для всех шорткодов на странице, то выходит очень много данных. Хочу сделать только при выполнении первого shortcod-а и вложить только для него.

Например, есть такой код shortcode:

```
function my_code_handler($atts)
{
$script = 'window.data = {ДАННЫЕ}';
wp_add_inline_script( 'script_name', $script, 'before' );
}

add_shortcode( 'code', 'my_code_handler' );
```

Страница Wordpress c шорткодами:

- [code] Как только для этого выполнять `wp_add_inline_script`?
- [code] А для этого игнорировать.
- [code] И для этого игнорировать.

То есть отдавать только для первого shortcod-а?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант создать статическую переменную, по которой вы можете отслеживать какой по счету шорткод встретился.

Например так:

```
function my_code_handler($atts)
{
    static $i = 0;
    if ($i == 0) {
        $script = 'window.data = {ДАННЫЕ}';
        wp_add_inline_script( 'script_name', $script, 'before' );
    }
    $i++;
}

add_shortcode( 'code', 'my_code_handler' );
```

Comment: Сработало. Но не могу понять, как. А в php можно объявить static в функции, не в методе? У меня тут класса нет.

Comment: Как вы могли убедиться на практике -- можно. Почитайте подробнее об этом [здесь](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Спасибо. А это, случаем, не создаст баг. Например, в двух новостных статьях я имею 3 шорткода в сумме. В первой новости 2, я должен отдать на один. Во второй новости 1, ему я должен отдать. А если функция одна, не окажется ли так, что данные я отдам на самый первый шорткод, только для одной статьи?

Comment: @Lasna, только при условии, что эти две новости будут на одной странице, а в содержимом страницы будут все три шорткода, т.к. при таком раскладе шорткод второй новости будет третьим по счету. В этом случае можно использовать, например, атрибуты шорткода, и отдавать `wp_add_inline_script` только при наличии определенного атрибута